# Loop mount over an array (name has a space)

Tags: shell-script, mount

So I'm trying to write a small script that loops over an array list like so

```
if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
   sudo "$0" "$@"
   exit $?
fi
echo "Please enter repo password"
stty -echo
read PASSWORD
stty echo
REPOS=("repo one" "repo 2" "repo 3")
for i in "${REPOS[@]}"
do
   sudo mount //$IPLOCATION/$i $MOUNTPATH/$i -o "username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWORD"
done
```

This seems to work well when the array is `REPOS=("repoone" "repotwo" "repothree")` But not with spaces. I tried with `repo\ one` and `repo\\\ one` but am getting no luck. I know I'm missing something stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `$i` between double quotes:

```
sudo mount "//$IPLOCATION/$i" "$MOUNTPATH/$i" -o "username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWORD"
```

Comment: I knew I was just missing something stupid. Thanks. I'll accept the answer when it lets me